# How can I parse raw file of Atop (Linux Utility) using Java?

Tags: java, linux

I hawe some raw files as a result of the launch atop utility.
Is it possible to parse them on Java?
Any ideas? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the raw files to ASCII `atop -r filename.raw > filename.txt` and then parse them in Java as usual.

I don't think there is a ready made Java library for parsing atop's binary raw format.